# necessary Information to connect with an SSO provider

Tags: single-sign-on

Say that I have an application (service provider), and sell it to clients. The clients want to use SSO login instead of logging in using the application's credentials. So I want to create something like this so that I won't have to modify source code every time a the usage of a new SSO provider(SP) is required.

1. Client will open some thing called SP manager page
2. Client click add new sso provider to open the SP creation page
3. Client enter the necessary information to connect to the SP
4. When done, the user click Save to save the information
5. The user turn the newly create SP' status to On (mean yes I will use sso with this SP)
6. The user then logout and login again. Now the application will automatically redirect the user to the SP login page , if the login is success , the user will be redirected back to the application and logged into the system.

What I'm confuse is, how much information will be needed to implement this. As far as I know the following information is necessary.

- SP's endpoint URL (the url to send SAML request to)
- Fingerprint ? (Token code ? )
  Is there anything else ?

One more thing, is the SAML format (layout definition) will be different for each SP or they will be all the same?

Thanks a lot for reading.

Comment: I think your best bet would be to support oauth2 / oidc providers. Its a well established standard with many certified implementations.

Answer (score 1):

Your question does not state the language, SDK, platform details about your app. I assume you have not yet incorporated the SSO login into your app. Assuming that your application will not just be browser-limited, you need a HTTP client tool library like

```
curl — https://curl.se/download.html
HTTPie — https://httpie.io/
Postman — https://www.postman.com/downloads/
Insomnia — https://insomnia.rest/
```

Since my personal favorite is curl - the flow will be somewhat like [this](https://www.ssocircle.com/en/developer-tutorial-saml-testing-using-curl-and-ssocheck-api/developer-tutorial-part-i-a-saml-sso-flow-from-the-command-line-with-curl/) -

- CLIENT accesses the SP (Initiate the SSO flow – this is typically a
  “sign in” button or simply a request to a protected page) SP replies
  with a SAML AuthnRequest message (typically a 302 redirect to the
  IDP)
- CLIENT follows the redirect and sends the SAML AuthnRequest message
  to IDP
- If user is not already authenticated with the IDP a. IDP redirects to
  the IDP login page b. CLIENT submits credentials vial the login form
  to IDP c. IDP authenticates the user and redirects the user to
  continue with SSO
- IDP generates the SAML Response with the Assertion and sends it back
  to the CLIENT (typically this is a HTML page with an auto-posted
  form)
- CLIENT continues posting the SAML Response message to the SP
- SP receives the SAML Response message and authenticates the user
  based on the Assertion (if SSO is successful the SP typically replies
  with a “logged in” page or the protected content)
- CLIENT receives the SP response and evaluates if the SSO flow was
  successful (user is logged in)

This example uses a bash script, you can also use the curl C++ API. However, from personal experience, using a script will be faster in terms of development time. You can test using the CLI, and when satisfied, you can incorporate the CLI using a pipe into your application using python or C++.

You can add text input fields in your app to ensure your requirement is satisfied - **I won't have to modify source code every time a the usage of a new SSO provider(SP) is required.**